# Почему следующая операция выдает -1?

Tags: java

```
double m = (byte) 110_987_654_6299.123_34;
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Справедливости ради стоит отметить, что результатом (значением `m`) будет `-1.0`, а не `-1`.

Происходят 3 действия:

1. `double` число `110_987_654_6299.123_34` приводится к `int`. Результатом будет `2147483647`
2. `int` число `2147483647` приводится к `byte`. Результатом будет `-1`
3. `byte` число `-1` приводится к `double`. Результатом будет `-1.0`

Почему приведение работает именно так - можно прочитать [в документации](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.3). 
Если вкратце, то:

- при приведении `double` к `byte` (правая часть выражения) сначала происходит приведение `double` к `int`, и только затем - `int` к `byte`
- приведение `double` к `int` в случае превышения допустимого `int` значения возвращает максимальное значение `int`
- приведение `int` к `byte` просто берёт последние 8 бит из `int`

Comment: теперь ясно, спасибо!

Comment: @Gennadyi, тогда прими ответ нажатием на галочку слева от него.

Comment: @Gennadyi нет, не приводится. Так заложено разработчиками: целочисленный тип сразу сужается к другому целочисленному типу путём отсечения "лишних" битов: _"A narrowing conversion of a signed integer to an integral type T simply discards all but the n lowest order bits, where n is the number of bits used to represent type T"_.